# Bash Script will not stop.

Tags: bash, ping, kill

So i had the bright idea of making a script that pings my IP to see if its up as i am having some issues with it. so here is  the script I made.

```
while : 
do 
      ping (IP address)
done
```

now it wont stop, I've tried control x, and z, but it still wont stop? Ive saved it under ~/ .bash_profile, any ideas? //sorry about the space, you know, stack exchange.

Comment: control-c is the break signal.  Otherwise, kill the process id of the script.

Comment: Reboot and login as a different user.  If your OS supports it ALT F2 to a second terminal windows.  ps -ef |grep  <script name>   kill -9 <pid of script name>

Comment: Should note that while the ping is running, i cant type anything, and i am on the defualt mac Os X terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Your can press Ctrl + C to stop things that's "not stopping". 
On some systems might be Ctrl + Break.

Anyway, sometimes it does not stop immediately, or it won't response to Ctrl + c due to high load of system resources. so you might want to press Ctrl + C many times.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

ping -c 1 8.8.8.8

Comment: Welcome to Super User! How will that kill the script that's running?